# Macro to paste completed items to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me fix a macro to paste completed items (Column A) to the next sheet (Completed Tab) then delete it from 1st sheet (Email Tracker) once transferred to Completed Tab. It's behaving like this:

-overwrites the contents in Completed tab, instead of adding additional entries to it

Below is my code.

```
Sub Clear()
'
' Clear Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
    Sheets("Email Tracker").Select
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Completed"
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
    Sheets("Completed").Select
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Email Tracker").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "Completed Item" mean?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I'm not actually a pro, I just record it using the "record macro" button then tries to debug the highlighted portion, if there is any. It overwrites the contents in Completed tab, instead of adding additional entries to it.

Comment: I’m guessing when you filter, you only want to grab visible cells? What is your last Column?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the macro recorder you should always try to clean up the code and remove "Select". I see where you tried to add last row, but didn't know how to apply it. The code below first sets up the last row (LR) for your destination sheet, so you can properly paste your "completed" emails to the first empty row after the last row in the Destination sheet. Next, it copies your headers from the source sheet to destination sheet, because I don't know if they are already in the destination sheet. Next it filters your source sheet and copies the visible data to your destination sheet, pasting the data to the first empty row below the last row. Then it will delete the visible data on your filtered source sheet. Finally it removes the filter in your source sheet.

```
Dim LR As Long

With Worksheets("Email Tracker")
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("A1")

    LR = Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Completed"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Completed").Cells(LR + 1, 1)
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Pros! Especially to GMalc for the code. When I tried the macro, it worked but when I press it again, it deletes even those items that are not yet complete in sheet 1. Please advice. Or is there a code that prohibits running the script if there are no completed items in row 1 sheet 1??

Comment: It runs even if there are no completed items in row 1 and deletes even the critical and open items... I'd like to show you the file but can't attach it here :(

<https://nofile.io/f/77oETcv2Gc7/Email+Tracker+-+Test+Macro.v3+(1).xlsm>